# Is it possible to restore an ElasticSearch snapshot from .dat files?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two .dat files sent to me by a colleague, (meta- and another one), can I restore (and how) an elasticsearch snapshot from it?

Comment: Please share some more information about the contents of the .dat files. Are they text based? Can you give us some example lines (anonymized)?

Comment: basicly, I have index file, containing object like:
{"snapshots":[{"name":"snapshot_2018_02_14","uuid":"TlZLDXjsSui6WTOJz5SUzg","state":1},{"name":"snapshot_2018_10_28","uuid":"tfKPomcSQRacdHtaQI6w_Q","state":2}, //etc]
Then, I have index.latest and meta-<someString>.dat and snap-<someString>.dat files, all of them are binary.

Comment: object like?????

Comment: Edited above, pls see

Comment: yes you can restore it if you know the elasticsearch version

Comment: Thanks, any practical recommendations?

Comment: For starters, `GET /` would get you the ES version

Comment: Anything for those who continues?

Answer (score 0):

first ask the version.

download elasticsearch and install it(not easy):
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/getting-started-install.html

use restore API:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/modules-snapshots.html

snapshot_2018_02_14 is the name of snapshot.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts, but it's more like 'use google to do this'